# Python: Take input json file and convert to output file (csv) (the naive way without csvwriter, pandas, dicwriter)

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I have a JSON file formatted as so:

```
[{
"x":"data",
"y":"data2",
"z": {
    "abc": [1,2,3,4],
    "efg": "data3"
     }
},
{
"x":"data4",
"y":"data5",
"n": "data6"
"z": {
    "abc": [1,2,3,4],
    "efg": "data6"
     }
}
]
```

We need to convert and write this to a csv output file where we can hardcode the headers (x,y,n,abc,efg), but need to get the data into csv format as so:

```
x,y,n,abc,efg
data,data1,(pass none/leave empty if no value),[1,2,3,4], data3
data4,data5,data6, [2,3,4,5], data7
```

I'm having trouble with trying to write out the data that is in the nested dictionary and would appreciate any help. ***We are not allowed to use pandas, csvwriter, dictwriter, etc. Have to do it the naive way***

I currently have:

```
def func(inputFile, outputFile):
 with open(inputFile, 'r') as file:
 jsonFile = json.load(file)
 with open(outputFile, 'w') as csvFile:
 csvFile.write('x,y,z,abc,efg\n')

return csvFile
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide a specific question along with code.

Comment: Updated with current code

Comment: Where's the code that tries to get and write values? This just writes the header.

Comment: Yeah, even if you can write english pseudocode to help me get started that'd be big!